# Can Google Maps show Terrain at 45 degrees

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I need the terrain view but cant seem to show it at 45 degrees. I dont want to use the google earth plug-in though. Can this be done? If not: are there other map apis that do this?

Answer (score 2):

It can't be done with Google Maps API. Tilted maps are only available with the satellite/aerial tiles.

The docs state "`setTilt()`: Sets the angle of incidence for aerial imagery (available for SATELLITE and HYBRID map types) measured in degrees from the viewport plane to the map plane. The only supported values are 0, indicating no angle of incidence (no tilt), and 45 indicating a tilt of 45deg."